# Redirect URL Containing åäö

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm moving my blog from Typepad to Wordpress but have a big problem. Among the urls that are exported from Typepad, many containing åäö. When they are imported WordPress changes all URLs and instead contains aao.

I need help with how to redirect all urls that contains åäö to the new urls. It's a total of about 1300 urls.

I am not a "hacker" and need a detailed description how I should do :)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule (.*)(å|ä)(.*) $1a$3 [R=302,L]
RewriteRule (.*)(ö)(.*) $1a$3 [R=302,L]
```